# The slider to make the text area taller does not work on iPad

Tags: bug, questions, answers, asking-questions, answering-questions

In questions and answers, the text area has a nice slider to make him taller.

Alas, on iPad, the slider does not work.

It would be nice to make the slider work.

Thank you.

I have Safari on iOS 7 on an iPad mini.